# What is the characteristic function?

Tags: game-theory

Im trying to model the following problem using the core and the shapley value but I can't understand how to define the characteristic function.

Problem:

Let S be a team consisting of 3 players A,B,C and an enemy team F.Both teams contest in 18 games and each player takes part in 6 games.Finally S team won.Player A managed to win in 5 out of 6 games.Player B in 3 out of 6 games and player C in 2 out of 6 games.The price was 18 meals of food.The contest committee is in a dilemma.Should they award the team with as many meals as many wins they had in total.Meaning each player of the winning team will get as many meals as many wins he/she had on the games?Or they should give each player an equal amount of meals(meaning 6 for each)? The players after the games ended wanted to get the maximum meals they can get(meaning 6 meals).What the committee should do?

Can anybody shed some light on how to define the charactiristic function(meaning the payoff v(m) of each coalition m)?

Comment: Not sure I see how this is a math question.  If the prize was $18$ units then the $S$ team should get $18$ units, yes?  How to distribute that within the team is up to the team.  There isn't an abstract mathematical principle of fairness.

Comment: But its not up to the team its up to the contest comitee.They make the decision for the players.

Comment: Also, though I'm not sure it matters, the competition rules are not clear.  You say that teams $S,F$ played $6$ games but you don't say how a winner was decided (though you suggest that teams $S$ won at least $5$ of the $6$ games).

Comment: In response to your comment:  Well, the committee can decide according to whatever principle it feels like.  There isn't any mathematical principle they are obliged to follow. Of course, they may seek to apply some mathematical principle but then you need to tell us what rule they seek to apply.

Comment: The comitee wants to either use the shapley value or the core as I mention above(I edited the question to be a bit more clear).